# How to calculate anfle of inclination of the plane

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I have 3 points A, B and C and their coordinates (x y z), which form the plane, at the very beginning form an equilateral triangle(with the same value of the Z coordinate); points B and C can change their coordinates Z (up and down); How will the angle of inclination of the plane change and in which direction, if we change the coordinates Z point B and C (separately, not the same for both Zc and Zb). It has to work as a formula, because I have plenty of diffrent points A B and C. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Compute the angle between the plane’s normal and the $z$-axis.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it

Comment: Continuing amd's comment: Compute the normal vector (the three components). You can use for example cross product for this. Then consider the vector along the $z$, axis, which is just $\hat{e}_z = (0,0,1)$. You can use dot product to calculate the angle between the normal vector and this unit vector.

Comment: Are you interested in the angel between the two plans - the original and the newly created by the movement?